# Calling promise multiple times can Cause problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

Due to asynchronous Ajax call we are using promise, So that other JS waiting for Ajax success object can access its updated property.

We've 300 JS which will call this promise, Do we've any constraint if so many JS will call promise, it might start pending or never resolved.

Please advise

Thanks in advance

```
(function () {
    window.myObject = window.myObject || {};
    let isProfileUpdated = false;

    myObject.waitforProfile = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let maxTry = 50;
        let currentTry = 0;
        let tryForProfile = function () {
            if (currentTry < maxTry && isProfileUpdated) {
                resolve();
            } else if (currentTry < maxTry) {
                currentTry++;
                setTimeout(tryForProfile, 350);
            }
            else {
                reject('profile never resolved');
            }
        }
        tryForProfile();
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'www.google.com',
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
                result = result.model;
                if (result != undefined) {
                    window.myObject.title = result.title
                    isProfileUpdated = true;
                }
            }
        });

})();
```

**Caller - We have so many callers dependent on MyObject properties**

```
function initalizeNavigation() {
        if (myObject.title !== "") {
            createAuthenicatedUtilityNav();
        } else {
            createSignedOutUtilityNav();
        }
    }

    myObject.waitforProfile(initalizeNavigation)
        .catch(function (message) {
            console.log(message)
        });
```

Comment: You can't call a promise.  Do you mean 300 points in the code are making the same Ajax call, are adding `then` listeners to a single promise (or `await` the promise) or something else? Please share some code examples in the post with the explanation.

Comment: @traktor Updated my question, hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

There several errors in the algorithm the code was written to follow. Program design needs to fixed before throwing out the code and replacing it. One **design** approach may be to

1. Create a global Promise object to be fulfilled with the user profile requested from the server in the ajax call is received at the front end. Call it, say, `profilePromise`.
2. Issue an ajax call to obtain the user profile. If it succeeds, resolve profilePromise`with the decoded profile object. If it fails, reject`profilePromise` with the notified error or error message.
3. Add a catch handler to `profilePromise` to inform the user to try again later (or whatever) if it becomes rejected. The posted code doesn't retry the server call so I haven't tried to include it here.
4. Set up a timeout to reject `profilePromise` if too much time has elapsed. If the timer calls back attempts to reject the promise after the ajax call has succeeded and fulfilled the promise, rejecting the promise is simply ignored - settled promise state and values are immutable.

The 300+ code points throughout the code can `await` `profilePromise` to get the user profile or, alternatively, call `profilePromise.then` with a fulfillment handler to be called with the profile object after it arrives.

The code points **must** process profile data in an `async` function by using syntax similar to

```
const profile = await profilePromise;
```

or add a fulfillment handler to process the data using syntax similar to

```
profilePromise.then( profile => { do specific thing with profile data});
```

What you **cannot** do is "call" the promise as if it were a function to get the profile, or make a synchronous function that magically returns profile data before it arrives back from the server.

Put error checking in the `.catch` handler added in step 3. There is no need to recheck throughout the code - the fulfillment handlers will never get called.

---

A totally different approach might be tp ensure critical parts of application code don't execute before the profile data has been obtained and placed in a global variable.

In a single page app this might involve modal overlays or hidden sections of HTML that prevent user interaction with the code before being allowed to do so.

---

Please research the use of `async` functions and the `await` operator, or adding fulfillment handlers to a promise using its `then` method if unfamiliar with them.